# Dynamic textbox add and dispose : Few text boxes not getting disposed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I am creating few text boxes in windows forms dynamically and at some point I `dispose` these

```
        Dim tb1 As New TextBox          'new textbox
        tb1.Name = "dtba"               'setname
        tb1.Location = New Point(stx, sty)  'location of textbox
        tb1.Text = arl(0)                   'assigning text
        tb1.Width = 80                      'setting width
        tb1.TabStop = False                 'no tabstop
        tb1.Enabled = False                 'disabled
        Me.Controls.Add(tb1)                'add to form
```

'Repeating same code for few more text boxes

```
            Dim tb2 As New TextBox
            tb2.Name = "dtbb"
            tb2.Location = New Point(stx + 80, sty)
            tb2.Text = arl(1)
            tb2.Width = 175
            tb2.TabStop = False
            tb2.Enabled = False
            Me.Controls.Add(tb2)
            Dim tb3 As New TextBox
            tb3.Name = "dtbc"
            tb3.Location = New Point(stx + 255, sty)
            tb3.Text = arl(2)
            tb3.Width = 125
            tb3.TabStop = False
            tb3.Enabled = False
            Me.Controls.Add(tb3)
            Dim tb4 As New TextBox
            tb4.Name = "dtbd"
            tb4.Location = New Point(stx + 380, sty)
            tb4.Text = arl(3)
            tb4.Width = 100
            tb4.TabStop = False
            tb4.Enabled = False
            Me.Controls.Add(tb4)
```

Problem occurring when I try to delete these text boxes. Code is

```
        For Each cControl In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
                Dim txt As TextBox = CType(cControl, TextBox)
                If txt.Name.Contains("dtb") Then
                    txt.Dispose()
                End If
            End If
        Next cControl
```

**Here the text boxes named `dtba` and `dtbc` getting deleted. But `dtbb` and `dtbd` are not getting deleted.** Any help ?

Comment: In the controls collection do you see the controls that are not being disposed?

Comment: @SamMakin : I checked all text boxes, but not found.

Comment: @SamMakin : No. Not even in controls. :(

Comment: Are you removing the controls in the same place as they are added?  Is 'Me' the same?

Comment: @SamMakin : Yes. And as you see two are getting removed, but two are not..

Comment: Recreated the problem - give me a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the collection whilst looping over it.  Try something like this instead:

```
    Dim l As New List(Of Control)

    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = CType(cControl, TextBox)
            If txt.Name.Contains("dtb") Then
                l.Add(cControl)
            End If
        End If
    Next cControl

    For Each c As Control In l
        c.Dispose()
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead utilize this:

```
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = CType(cControl, TextBox)
            If txt.Name.Contains("dtb") Then
                txt.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
    Next cControl
```

Do this:

```
    Again:
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = CType(cControl, TextBox)
            If txt.Name.Contains("dtb") Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(txt)
                GoTo again
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The problem is related to INDEX of FOR EACH, that loss the pointer when the controls is deleted.  You must repeat the operation to ensure a new index.